# javascript REGex remove single quote in match

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var RegTxt =  "$f1$='test' AND f2='test2'";
alert(RegTxt.match(/\'[^\']*'/g))
```

returns the match correctely i:e 'test','test2' but how can i remove the single quote in the match.

Answer (score 3):

This would be quite simple if JavaScript supported negative lookbehinds:

```
/(?<=').*?(?=')/
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't.

In cases like these I like to *ab*use `String.prototype.replace`:

```
// btw, RegTxt should start with a lowercase 'r', as per convention
var match = [];
regTxt.replace(/'([^']*)'/g, function($0, $1){
    match.push($1);
});
match; // => ['test', 'test2']
```

Comment: >>RegTxt should start with a lowercase 'r', as per convention.
What Convention? This is very subjective and there are many opinions on this subject!

Comment: A capital first character, in JavaScript, indicates a constructor. Like I said, it's a convention. See [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=Crockford+capital+constructor&source=bl&ots=HHshq8r2dL&sig=l3N7p2R9OeVl5s42pT8hophevgs&hl=en&ei=YWm7S4eiK4ay-Abjq_zNCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false) *(... wondering why I've been down-voted)*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crude solution to your problem.

```
var match = RegTxt.match(/\'[^\']*'/g)
match = match.substring(1, match.length - 2);
```

Comment: It would be nice to know why the down-votes, based on the fact that this does functionally work and I did mention that it is a crude solution.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial approach:

```
RegTxt.replace(/'/g, "")
```

using your regex:

```
RegTxt.replace(/\'([^\']*)'/g, "$1")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var matches = str.match(regex);
var newMatches = [];
for( i in matches )
{
var word = matches[i];
newMatches.push( word.substring(1,word.length-1))
}
```

`newMatches` will now contain the array you need.